# Algorithm to return unique values from unsorted input

Tags: java, algorithm, unique

I need to create an efficient algorithm that returns unique values from an unsorted input. I don't know the length of the input.

As the function that will call this algorithm can abort the reading at any time, I think that using a well defined `Iterable` implementation is the right way, so I will not waste extra processing power for the uneeded input.

Today, I am using a `Set` to keep track of the values I've already read. But I don't know if this is the most efficient algorithm, as my input length can be huge.

The code below is my today's working algorithm:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UniqueValues implements Iterable<String> {
    private final Iterator<String> iterator;

    public UniqueValues(BufferedReader r) {
        this.iterator = new UniqueValuesIterator(r);
    }

    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return iterator;
    }

    static class UniqueValuesIterator implements Iterator<String> {
        private final BufferedReader r;

        private final Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();

        // When 'next' is null, need to get the next value
        private String next;

        public UniqueValuesIterator(BufferedReader r) {
            this.r = r;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            // Good point from OldCurmudgeon
            if(next != null) return true;

            try {
                String line;
                while((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(values.add(line)) { // add() returns 'true' when it is not a duplicate value.
                        next = line;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } catch(IOException e) { }

            return false;
        }

        public String next() {
            if(next == null) {
                if(! hasNext() ) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }

            final String temp = next;
            next = null;
            return temp;
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    // For testing
    public static void main(String... args) {
        final StringReader r = new StringReader("value1\nvalue6\nvalue1\nvalue3\nvalue3\nvalue6\nvalue1\nvalue6");

        for(final String value : new UniqueValues(new BufferedReader(r)) ) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }

        /* Output is (order is not important):
         * 
         * line 1
         * line 6
         * line 3
         */
    }
}
```

Does it have any better algorithm to do this?

Comment: You might get answers better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should protect your `hasNext` with a `if ( next != null )`. It is perfectly acceptable for a user to call `hasNext` as often as it likes without calling `next`. You will step on to the next item in that case.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be fine however I would be tempted to make the code less generic unless this is something you do often.

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
     Set<String> lines = new HashSet<>();
     for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
        if(lines.add(line)) {
            // do something
        }
     }
 }
```

or if you have to return an Iterable you can do

```
public static Set<String> uniqueLines(File file) {
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
         Set<String> lines = new HashSet<>();
         for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;)
            lines.add(line))
         return lines;
     }
 }
```

Comment: @dudinha-dedalus, Set has iterator() method, it can return iterate-able collection

Comment: @dudinha-dedalus It is not clear why this is a requirement, but you can use the second example.

Comment: @PeterLawrey In the second example, the code will read all input (that can be huge), and take a very long time before the main code can start processing something. Using my approach, as soon as there is any unique data, the main code can process and, if it doesn't need any more data, it can just stop using the iterator. Does it make sense?

Comment: @dudinha-dedalus It makes sense, however the amount of work done by the thread is likely to be the same and it might actually finish earlier using one approach or the other depending on how it is used.

Answer (score 1):

In case your input consists only of strings, you can use [a trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to keep track of them. It has O(string length) lookup and insertion time, and is more space-efficient than a hash map.

One caveat, though: a trie has a rather significant overhead per tree node, so it becomes more efficient only when input is large enough and its elements are similar enough. It won't give any benefits for randomly generated strings, for example.